# Tecla pressionada em C++

Tags: c, c++

Como posso detectar se a tecla Ctrl foi pressionada em C++?
Preciso especificamente da tecla Ctrl

Comment: Em Windows pode usar algo simples como `GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL);` que retorna 0 se a tecla não está pressionada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int GetControlState()
{
    return (int) GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
}
```

Em `Windows` algo simples assim retorna `1` se CONTROL está ativa. `VK_LCONTROL` e `VK_RCONTROL` são os códigos das teclas esquerda e direita se precisar diferenciar. É meio confuso o *reset* desses status e pode ser mais eficiente usar `GetAsyncKeyState)` como descrito na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate)

Comment: :) Ao menos 3 vigilantes usuários em dois dias classificaram minha resposta como inútil. Pena que não disseram como eu posso melhorar a resposta ao nível esperado. Apenas responder a pergunta e agregar código e link para a documentação em portuguêm foi pouco.

Answer (score -4):

A tecla ctrl não tem um valor em específico a tabela ascii, ela só é reconhecida pelos programas ao se usada junto a outra, as demais você pode pegar o valor com a função **getchar();**

Comment: Em Windows Control é `VK_CONTROL`. Se precisar diferenciar a esquerda e a direita também tem seus valores específicos: `VK_LCONTROL` e `VK_RCONTROL`. No `Unix`/`Linux`/`Mac` é similar. Esqueça `getchar()` que não é para isso.